# How to quantize floating point to unsigned byte in GLSL

Tags: c++, opengl, floating-point, glsl

I used floating point texture as data buffer in GLSL and need to save the data on a normal texture (each pixel's color has 1 byte). In my situation, floating point is [-2048.0, 2048.0] and so I have to quantize [-2048.0, 2048.0] to [0, 255]. I think the C++ code for this problem is like :

```
//*quantization*
float fvalue = ... ;  // floating point data
fvalue /= 16.0f;  // [-128.0, 128.0]
fvalue = roundf(fvalue);  // [-128, 128]
if(fvalue > 127.0f) fvalue = 127.0f;
else if(fvalue < -128.0f) fvalue = -128.0f;
u_char byte = (int)fvalue + 128;  // [0, 255]

//*inverse quantization*
u_char byte = ...;  // [0, 255]
float fvalue = byte - 128;  // [-128, 127]
fvalue *= 16.0f;  // [-2048, 2032] (it can't be helped?)
```

I'm not certain this code is good, but moreover I'm not really sure what is great in GLSL (GLSL handles byte value [0, 255] as floating point [0.0, 1.0]). My code is :

```
//*quantization*
vec3 F = ...;  //F is floating vector [-2048.0, 2048.0]
F /= 16;  // [-128.0, 128.0]
F /= 256;  // [-0.5, 0.5]
F += vec3(0.50f);  // [0.0, 1.0]
gl_FragData[0] = vec4(F, 1.0);

//*inverse quantization*
vec3 F = texture2D(...); //byte data [0.0, 1.0]
F -= vec3(0.50f); //byte data [-0.5, 0.5]
F *= 256; //[-128, 128]
F *= 16; //[-2048, 2048]
```

This didn't work well. However, if I rewrite codes `F += vec3(0.50f);` to `F += vec3(0.51f);` and also `F -= vec3(0.50f);` to `F -= vec3(0.51f);`, It seems works well. But I don't think the value `0.51f` is reasonable. In fact, this works well in one hardware, while this doesn't work well in another hardware.
 I want to know the good way to quantize (also inv-quantize) float values.

Comment: Define "didn't work well". Also, what versions of OpenGL are you allowed to use?

Comment: It means "didn't quantize well"; if I convert floating point `f` to intefer `b` and again to `f'`, the error `f-f'` is large. I use OpenGL 2.0 (also OpenGL ES 2.0).

Comment: How large? Is the error unreasonably large? Post actual numbers.

Comment: It's very hard to get actual value of texture's pixel in GLSL. It, however, can be said as large as I can "see" the error. Let's say I want to compress an image data which is to be decompressed. It's ideal to get the same image after decompression, but impossible because these processes needs quantization and inverse quantization. If the image becomes somewhat degraded, it's a small error. However, if a white pixel of the image becomes a green pixel, it's a large error, which I can "see".

Comment: "*It's very hard to get actual value of texture's pixel in GLSL.*" You use `glGetTexImage`. Downloading texel data isn't that different from uploading it.

Answer (score 1):

I can find the way which works "well". I'm afraid to say I can't explain reasonably why it works and so I don't know whether this is versatile method.

```
//*quantization*
vec3 F = ...;  //F is floating vector [-2048.0, 2048.0]
F += 2048;
F /= 16;
F /= 255;
gl_FragData[0] = vec4(F, 1.0);

//*inverse quantization*
vec3 F = texture2D(...);  //byte data [0.0, 1.0]
F *= 255.0;
F *= 16.0;
F -= vec3(2048 + 8);  //adding bias -16.0/2.0
F = 2.0 * F * qp * Q / 16.0;
```

Comment: I think you are overthinking it. Just to one multiply and add to change the range. F' = F*(.5/2048.0)+.5. Why multiple integer divides? And the inverse is just F=(F'-.5)*(2048.0*2.0)=F'*2048.0*2.0-2048.0. Both of those will compile to a single MAD instruction. The generic way to go from [a..b] to [0..1] is x'=(x-a)/(b-a) = x/(b-a) - a/(b-a).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, each pixel having 1 byte does not adequately convey what you are trying to describe. This so-called "normal texture" is more accurately referred to as "unsigned normalized" (often shortened to `unorm`).

You want an 8-bit unorm texture here (ideally with multiple components); these are textures that store fixed-point data and are treated like floating-point (in the range [**0.0**,**1.0**]) when sampled by normalizing the data to its intrinsic range (*e.g.* promoting to floating-point and dividing by **255.0**).

Given what was just described, you simply need to transform the original data [**-2048.0**,**2048.0**] into [**0.0**,**1.0**] and then multiply by **255**.

This is rather undesirable though, because you will lose the ability to represent the original range without severe aliasing. Instead, multiply by **4294967295** (**256<sup>4</sup>**-**1**) and pack 8-bits into R, 8-bits into G, 8-bits into B and 8-bits into A. You have made no attempt to pack the components in the shader shown.